# $PATH variable not properly set in gvim/MacVim when it is opened from the finder

Tags: macos, vim, command-line, path, macvim

I am using MacVim (basically gvim for the mac).

If I open macvim from the command line then my `$PATH` variable will be properly set.

If I open macvim via point and click with the finder, the `$PATH` variable will NOT be properly set.

Can anyone give me some insight?

Note: I know at least part of my path is set in `~/.bashrc`, but I am not sure where the rest of it is set.

---

**Examples:**

If I open macvim from the terminal:

```
% gvim basic.tex
```

And then in MacVim I go:

```
:!echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/sw/bin:/sw/sbin:/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/M
acOS:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

This is the right path.

---

When I open the file with the mouse (in finder)

When I go:

```
:!echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

It gives me a little path.  Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The place to set environment variables
on the Mac for GUI applications (those started via loginwindow, the
Finder, etc.) is `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`

Alternately in MacVim you can choose to launch vim processes in a login-shell (look in the preferences).

For more info see [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_mac/browse_thread/thread/c124bfd73ba34b2a/ffbaa45851ef6e1b?lnk=gst&q=finder+%24PATH+#ffbaa45851ef6e1b).

Comment: The option to launch vim processes in a login-shell is not available in MacVim 7.3 anymore.

Comment: For an answer that works in 2021, see this approach https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/289062/33737 .

Answer (score 16):

I had this same issue but it only appeared after setting my default shell to zsh like so

```
export SHELL=/bin/zsh
```

It seems that there is a bug in the OS X zsh setup. The work around in brief is to merge `/etc/zshenv` into `/etc/zprofile`. In my case I didn't have a `/etc/zprofile` so just moving over the file did the trick:

`sudo mv /etc/zshenv /etc/zprofile`

This [post](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/MacVim-and-PATH-td3388705.html) describes the solution in more detail.

Comment: This is the solution mentioned on the official MacVim github wiki: https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/wiki/Troubleshooting (under the "For zsh users" heading)

Comment: I think maybe the key is getting the eval /usr/libexec/path_helper -s command out of `/etc/zshenv`.  I find the word "merge" in the answer confusing.  Still, very helpful, Thx.  Upvote!

Comment: Instead of using the system `/etc/zprofile` you can use your own `~/.zprofile`

Comment: in my case I just moved all my export PATH things from ~/.zshrc into ~/.zprofile the doc says to copy them and do a typeset but there is no need

Comment: The only thing that worked for me was `ln -s ~/.zshrc ~/.zprofile`

Comment: Since the question mentioned the user's `~/.bashrc` file, this answer about zsh doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: is it bad if I put this answers code in `zprofile` and change `bashrc` to `zshrc`? it seems to work... but im not sure if this is wrong. I want the path to update dynamically https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345345/794481

Answer (score 10):

For me, simply creating a new symbolic link from .zprofile to .zshrc did the trick:

```
ln -s ~/.zshrc ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: this works for me. it's a simplest workaround.
just change from `.zsrrc` to `.zshrc`

Comment: Or just define your paths in .zprofile instead of .zshrc.

Answer (score 3):

The difference in the PATHs probably has something to do with the difference between a login shell (logging in) and a non-login shell (bringing up a console).

From the bash man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell ... it looks for ~/.bash_profile...
>
> When  an  interactive  shell  that  is  not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc...

What I did to get around this issue was to add the following code to my `~/.bash_profile`, telling it to source my `~/.bashrc` if it exists:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: Won't this result in bashrc being loaded twice when it is an interactive shell?

Comment: I don't believe that it will get loaded twice. Now that I think about it, this isn't a solution to your problem... This solves the issue where you're logging in remotely (e.g. via ssh) and your `~/.bashrc` doesn't get loaded.  You're not remotely logging in.

Comment: But when you open a terminal *normally*, it will load your `.bash_profile` then it will load your `.bashrc` (maybe opposite order).  What you are doing will make it; `.bash_profile` which will load your `.bashrc` then it will load your `.bashrc`.  Probably this doesn't matter but if you wanted to do a work around, you could have a var `$BASHRC_LOADED` in your `.bashrc` and enclose everything in `if(not($BASHRC_LOADED))`.  *(sorry bad syntax)*

Comment: With the system I'm on now (Ubuntu 10.4) when I open a terminal it loads my `.bashrc` only.  If I ssh into the same box, it loads my `.bash_profile`.  I believe this is the way bash usually works.  As a side note, for each user, Ubuntu sets up a `.profile` file (which gets loaded if `.bash_profile` doesn't exist) that sources your `.bashrc` if it exists, much like what I mentioned above.