# Regenerate ctags in vim using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim, rubygems, ctags

I have the following code in my .vimrc:

```
map <Leader>rt :!ctags --extra=+f -R *<CR><CR>
```

This generates ctags for my current directory.

I'm using RVM, I'm working on different projects, with different ruby versions (trough RVM gemsets.

I have a different $GEM_PATH per project, and I want to generate the ctags for the gems in this path too.

How should the above line be to test if the $GEM_PATH variable is set, and processing these paths too?

Or better still how to check if I have an .rvmrc file, and generate ctags depending of the contents of this file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I use bundler to manage gems, so I use

```
ctags -R `bundle show rails`/../*
```

to get the tags for gems.

Comment: There should be backtics around the bundle command—can't get SO to render those properly

Comment: If you've upgraded gems then `\`bundle show rails\`` will tag all of the gems you've ever used. Better to use something like this: 


`ctags -e --exclude=.git --exclude='*.log' -R * \`bundle show --paths\``

Answer (score 11):

If you're using rvm, you can use `rvm gemdir`. For example, this is what I'm using:

```
map <Leader>rt :!ctags --extra=+f --exclude=.git --exclude=log -R * `rvm gemdir`/gems/*<CR><CR>
```

This will always use the gem directory in your current rvm gemset.

Comment: Is it possible to use this to generate tags only for the latest version of each gem?

Answer (score 6):

Generic version for tagging all the installed gems (it takes a while):

```
map <silent><Leader>rt :!ctags --extra=+f --exclude=.git --exclude=log -R * `gem environment gemdir`/gems/*<CR><CR>
```

If you want to just tag bundled gems (much faster):

```
map <silent> <Leader>rt :!bundle list --paths=true \| xargs ctags --extra=+f --exclude=.git --exclude=log -R *<CR><CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

This works well for me:

```
map <Leader>rt :!/usr/local/bin/ctags --language-force=ruby --exclude=.git --exclude=log -R * `bundle show --paths`
```

Adding --language-force=ruby in order to reduce the size of tags file and make it clean.

Answer (score 2):

That is what I use:

```
ctags -R --exclude=.git --exclude=log * $(rvm gemdir)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you in your situation by I do know of a quirk on macs that require me to run `sudo mv /etc/zshenv /etc/zprofile` every time I install vim to get exuberant with Rails.vim (Rtags) to work. For more see this post:

[$PATH variable not properly set in gvim/MacVim when it is opened from the finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344704/path-variable-not-properly-set-in-gvim-macvim-when-it-is-opened-from-the-finder)